# Quick probability question regarding not-so-obvious answer

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider an experiment that consists of determining the type of job, either blue- collar or white-collar, and the political affiliation, Republican, Democratic, or Independent, of the 15 members of an adult soccer team.

How many outcomes are
• (a) in the sample space?

The answer is not $2*3*15$ although I thought it was. How do I solve for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each person has $2*3=6$ possible cases.  You have to multiply them all together, getting $6^{15}$

Comment: Ahh, my slides said 615, a formatting error. Thanks!

Comment: Hence each living human being belongs to at least 60+ different teams, all made of a unique member (if the teams have more than one member, multiply).